# datatool - Precautions for lines not becoming too long when writing .csv-file/text-file from database?

Tags: datatool

This question refers to the LaTeX 2ε-package [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool):

You can save a database to .csv-file, which is a text-file, via
`\DTLsavedb{⟨db name⟩}{⟨filename⟩}`

You can load a database from .csv-file, which is a text-file, via
`\DTLloaddb/\DTLloadrawdb[⟨options⟩]{⟨db name⟩}{⟨filename⟩}`

**My question in this context is:**

**Are there any precautions taken in the datatool package for the case of lines of the text file/.csv-file becoming very long/too long?**

If yes: Which ones?

What is the maximum line length/the maximum number of characters per line when writing a database to .csv-file/text-file?

How to keep track of the number of characters still available in a row of the database so that when writing the .csv-file things still fit into a line of a text-file/.csv-file?

What is the maximum line length/the maximum number of characters per line when reading a database from .csv-file/text-file?

Where can I find more information about all this?